# Console URL in oozie job mail action

Tags: oozie

When an oozie node fails, I'm trying to get the console URL of the failing node sent in an email to me.

Currently my mail action looks like this:

```
<action name="send_error_email">
    <email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
        <to>${recipient}</to>
        <subject>Failure - ${DATE}
        </subject>
        <body>workflow ${wf:id()} failed.
Failing node: ${wf:lastErrorNode()}
Error code: ${wf:errorCode(wf:lastErrorNode())}
Error message: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}
Action Data: ${wf:actionData(wf:lastErrorNode())}
</body>
    </email>
    <ok to="fail" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
```

The action data is always sent empty...

Looking [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.3_Workflow_EL_Functions) there are several other functions such as `wf:actionTrackerUri` and `wf:actionExternalStatus` but nothing seems to return the Console URL...

Does anyone know of a way/workaround to get the Console URL?

Comment: I have same question, were you able to get the console url?

Comment: @ChiragKothari Unfortunately, no. It might be impossible to do, I don't have the time to look into it...